# Execute python script while open terminal

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, terminal, fish

I want this: Execute python script while I open terminal (I am using `iTerm` and `fish-shell`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [fish-shell](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html) was new to me, so I read the documentation - something I really recommend.  Look for the title "**Initialisation Files**": http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#initialization

So it looked like you call your python scripts from `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

So I installed `fish` on my Macbook and I had to create the `config.fish` file.  In that I just placed:

```
~/gash.py
```

That executes the python program `gash.py` in my home directory.  Of course the #! line has to be correct and I have to have execute permissions (as usual).  I entered the `fish` shell and it executed the program.

Thanks for that, the `fish-shell` looks quite interesting.  I love stackoverflow.